# RSpec Controller test, testing a post action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Right now I have a `subscriber` controller that creates a subscriber but that is not what I want to test. I also have a method in the controller that add 1 to the visit attribute on the Subscriber(I'll post the code) that is the method I want to test but I'm not sure how? I'm new to rails and Rspec so I'm having trouble grasping the concepts. I'll post my test and controller for clarity.

CONTROLLER:

```
def search
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new
end

def visit
  @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
   if @subscriber
    @subscriber.visit =+ 1
    @subscriber.save
    flash[:notice] = "thanks"
    redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:subscriber)
  else
    render "search"
  end
end
```

TEST

```
it "adds 1 to the visit attribute" do
  sign_in(user)
  subscriber = FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber)
  visits_before = subscriber.visit
  post :create, phone_number: subscriber.phone_number
  subscriber.reload

  expect(subscriber.visit).to eq(visits_before)
end
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

[image]

As you can see that is the method I want to test. The current test in place does not work but I thought it might help to show what I'm thinking. Hopefully this is enough info, let me know if you want to see anything else?

Comment: That's exactly what I answered you, visits is a method of an Instance, not a class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
it 'adds 1 to the visit attribute' do
  # I'm assuming you need this, and you are creating the user before
  sign_in(user)
  # I'm assuming your factory is correct
  subscriber = FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber) 
  visits_before = subscriber.visit
  post :create, subscriber: { phone_number: subscriber.phone_number }
  subscriber.reload
  expect(subscriber.visit).to eq(visits_before)
end
```

Comment: I like this implementation but when I set it to this I still got an error. I posted the latest error in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are checking `subscriber.visits` you should change `Subscriber` to `subscriber`:

```
expect { post :create, :subscriber => subscriber }.to change(subscriber, :visit).by(1)
```

`visits` is a method of an instance, not a class method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're testing the wrong method.  You've already stated that your `create` action works, so no need to test it here.  Unit tests are all about isolating the method under test.

Your test as it is written is testing that `post :create` does something.  If you want to test that your `visit` method does something, you'd need to do something like this:

```
describe "#GET visit" do
  before { allow(Subscriber).to receive(:find).and_return(subscriber) }
  let(:subscriber) { FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber) }

  it "adds one to the visit attribute" do
    sign_in(user)
    expect { get :visit }.to change(subscriber, :visit).by(1)
  end
end
```